# Question about debug trap

Tags: shell-script, debugging, trap

I have a script as below:

```
function dbgtrap {
echo "badvar is $badvar" 
}

badvar=0

function some_func {
    badvar=1
    badvar=2
    badvar=3
}

set -o functrace

trap dbgtrap DEBUG
    some_func
trap - DEBUG    # turn off the DEBUG trap
```

After I source the script, I got the output:

```
badvar is 0
badvar is 0
badvar is 0
badvar is 1
badvar is 2
badvar is 3
```

I was expecting sth like:

```
badvar is 0
badvar is 1
badvar is 2
badvar is 3
```

Where do the first two lines of the output come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trap is invoked after every command line once set.  As shown by using the TRACE output below:

```
+ badvar=0
+ set -o functrace
+ trap dbgtrap DEBUG
++ dbgtrap
++ echo 'badvar is 0'
badvar is 0
+ some_func
++ dbgtrap
++ echo 'badvar is 0'
badvar is 0
++ dbgtrap
++ echo 'badvar is 0'
badvar is 0
+ badvar=1
++ dbgtrap
++ echo 'badvar is 1'
badvar is 1
+ badvar=2
++ dbgtrap
++ echo 'badvar is 2'
badvar is 2
+ badvar=3
++ dbgtrap
++ echo 'badvar is 3'
badvar is 3
+ trap - DEBUG
```

IIRC shell invokes the trap at end of processing hence the 3 lines of output before the function call output of badvar values.

Comment: after every command, and (per bash manual) "before the first command executes in a shell function", which covers the third copy of "badvar is 0"

Comment: can you please tell me what the "++" sign means in this TRACE output?

Comment: [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):  The first character of PS4 is replicated multiple times, as necessary, to indicate multiple levels of indirection. The default is ''+ ''.